# Android and IOS download directory in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, download

How to get Android and ios download folder directory on flutter? I need to upload the files there

Comment: You can use the path_provider package: https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider - The documents directory can be retrieved with `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` and the temp directory can be retrieved with  `getTemporaryDirectory()`

Comment: android and ios downloads not supported. look -> https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider#:~:text=%E2%9D%8C%EF%B8%8F-,Downloads,-%E2%9D%8C